# sqlite3 one_file VFS Fails

Tags: c, sqlite, vfs

I was trying to run test_onefile.c example from [sqlite3 VFS examples](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html), and I get the following failure:

```
test_onefile: test_onefile.c:693: fsDelete: Assertion `strpcmp("-journal", &zPath[nName])==0' failed.
```

I'm running the code as follows:

```
int retval;
fs_register();
int q_cnt = 5,q_size = 150,ind = 0;
char **queries = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char) * q_cnt * q_size);


sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
sqlite3 *handle;

retval =  sqlite3_open_v2( "sampledb.sqlite2", &handle, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE , "fs");       


  if(retval)
  {
      printf("Database connection failed\n");
      return -1;
  }
  printf("Connection successful\n");

  // Create the SQL query for creating a table
  char create_table[100] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (uname TEXT,pass TEXT NOT NULL,activated INTEGER)";

  // Execute the query for creating the table
  retval = sqlite3_exec(handle,create_table,0,0,0);

  // Insert first row and second row
  queries[ind++] = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('manish','mani',1)";
  retval = sqlite3_exec(handle,queries[ind-1],0,0,0);
  queries[ind++] = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('mehul','pulsar',0)";
  retval = sqlite3_exec(handle,queries[ind-1],0,0,0);
```

Edit:
The file it fails on is `sampledb.sqlite2-wal`, clearly not a journal file. However, I don't understand how it reached it.

Edit2:
Well, after removing the assertion in source file:

`assert(strcmp("-journal", &zPath[nName])==0);`

The code seems to work. However, I'm not a big fan of assertion deletion, as clearly it would lead to some unexpected behavior. The author had a reason to use the assertion.

Comment: might be it give you assertion on that your comparison fails ( does not match two string). so it  break the execution from that point.

Comment: Nope. The exact code works with the default VFS and the demo VFS. It fails in assertion because it is trying to delete a `-wal` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VFS implemented by `test_onefile.c` is quite old, and therefore does not support the additional files required for WAL mode.

To make it work with a modern SQLite, the `fsDelete` function should just ignore attempts to delete `-wal` or `-shm` files.

Comment: Is there a way to disable wal mode from C api? I was sure that by default `WAL` mode is disabled. I'm fine with having just journal files. I'v made changes to `test_onefile.c` in order to read/write directly to raw device (assuming one db per partition), without using the underlying vfs (which uses fs calls). So far, without the assertion, it seems to work fine. However, I have a feeling that those files (`wal`,`shm`) will somehow throw errors.

Comment: The problem is not that WAL mode is enabled, but that the new SQLite tries to delete the WAL files just to be sure.