# how to let sqlite3 work on a raw device

Tags: sqlite

I want to user sqlite3 on raw device. I have used [sqlite3 one_file VFS Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279831/sqlite3-one-file-vfs-fails) for reference to test.

1. Compile test_onefile.c with sqlite3 library
2. Replace 'fs_register()' with 'SqlitetestOnefile_Init()'
3. Create raw device '/dev/sdb'
4. sqlite3_open_v2("/dev/sdb", &handle, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE , "fs");
5. Modify code: create table,insert data and select data.
6. First run, that's ok. continue i only run select data, it's talk '[error 1:no such table: users]'.

I don't know reason.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite needs to create temporary files in the same directory where the database is. This does not work with raw devices. They will be put into the /dev folder, which is not intended in most cases.